# Events Addon? Need something like Meetup.com

Tags: add-on, members, addons

I need to sell "events" to registered members of my EE site. Requirements are as follows:

1. Admin shall be able to create an event. An event is defined as having a start date/time, maybe an end date/time, a venue for the event, and a description.
2. Admin shall be able to set "pricing rules" for the event, primarily based around member details. For example, it's $0 for women, $10 for men, etc.
3. Admin shall be able to set quotas for the the event, primarily based around member details. For example, allow 10 men and 10 women to register for the event. Or allow 20 members to register, regardless of gender. Etc.
4. Allow members to register for the event. If the event requires payment, then process the member's payment.

Is there a native EE addon for this? If not, is there some 3rd party addon I can look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could conceivably build a solution using Cartthrob and Profile:Edit in conjunction - as your events could be simple channel entries. It would seem your "customers" would need to register for the site, with some sort of required "gender" field, which could then control which events would be visible, and to whom, or available for purchase. You could probably use price modifiers per event based on the cost per gender.

But it could potentially require some custom work for the products - i.e. for the quotas - you might need a custom extension for inventory - and how would you even begin to enforce the gender aspect?

Comment: I'm using Safecracker Registration. Members do sign up and are required to set their gender. I suppose I could simply build a Channel for events that had all the fields I need. I suppose I could use the Members' data and the Events' date to enforce some rules over who can register for the event. I've never used Cartthrob, but I suppose I could create, for example, "tickets" in the inventory system that can be purchased by members for a particular event. Is that the general idea you had?

Comment: Your events would live within the products channel used by Cartthrob - you could set gender as a price modifier; e.g. base price $0 male price +$10 and set the inventory for each modifier I believe. Then conceivably, you'd be able to test against your member field to display the option to the current user and sell an event's "ticket" based on that? This is a hypothetical, but I think it would work. Check the CT docs on price modifiers, etc… I've never used Safecracker Registration, but they're all variations on a theme…

Comment: I'm wondering now if this is something I can just implement on my own using Channels (no more Cartthrob). You've given me things to think of. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible out of the box with ExpressionEngine. The only 3rd party events add-on that I was able to find is [Low Events](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-events), which doesn't appear to do everything  you need/want it to do.

The most complex part is likely to be the "pricing rules" and "quotas". It seems to me that you're likely to need a custom addon for that.